# Silverlight + Entity Framework not changing boolean field from True to False

Tags: c#, silverlight, boolean, wcf-ria-services, entity-framework-6

I have a Silverlight Application using RIA Services (latest official version) and Entity Framework 6 with T4 tempalte generator. I had a table to which I added a new boolean field 'MyBooleanField'. When adding a new entity and committing changes, it saves normally without any abnormalities, but when I try to update an existing entity MyBooleanField's value, I have two cases:

from False to True : it works normally

from True to False : it doesn't save the changes to the Db.

Putting breakpoints in different positions in my code, I noticed that the changes ARE sent to the server in both cases, but in the second one (true to false), the changes aren't persisted in the database ???!!!

Any help is appreciated.